# Removing cinemascope frame from image in flutter

Tags: image, flutter

I have image with cinemascope(Black bars on top and bottom). I want to show it in FadeInImage without these bars.

[image]

The size box is in a column and row. The column has parent Card. I am unable to post full code.

```
SizedBox(
                    height: cardHeight,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: width * 0.20/cardHeight,
                            child: FadeInImage(
                              placeholder: Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/blank.png',
                              ).image,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Y8v23Cg4EBw/default.jpg',
                              ),
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Could you show code you ajave written so far?

Answer (score 0):

Could do:

```
    AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 16.0 / 9.0, // whatever ratio your img is
        child:FadeInImage(fit:BoxFit.fitWidth ...) // or test other fits
    )
```

Comment: Sorry. I missed adding size for SizeBox. It is working . But i do not want increase the width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Could Do

```
fit: BoxFit.none,
```

inside of your image view